# Загрузка папки с файлами на сервер через веб-интерфейс

Tags: java, веб-программирование, fileupload

Изучаю джаву. Имеется веб-форма для загрузки файла на сервер. Используя spring и commons fileupload получилось загрузить одиночный файл. Как теперь решить эту задачу, выбирая папку, а не файл, чтобы загружалась вся папка? Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: Это вопрос к клиентской части. Берете виджет который поддерживает multiupload, папка = список файлов, они просто загружаются по очереди, на сервере ничего менять не нужно. [Пример виджета](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic-plus.html).

Comment: Спасибо. То, что нужно